# Cisco Packet Tracer Connection Error - The cable cannot be connected to that port

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

There are 3 NICs in the Router1 and 24 available ports in the Switch1.

[image]

Is there any reason why I can't connect from Router1 to Switch1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't connect more than 2 links.

The workaround is to add new gigabit ports to your routers.

The module name is `NIM-ES2-4` (see picture).

Just drag and drop it to available slots.

Btw, you need to turn off the router, else you can't add the module.

[image]